# Chrome in Android gone refreshing the page it self when i did selected an option

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, web

i'm new in programming. i have created a simple page, simply the page we can call as a form who has One Option Value, Three textbox, and 2 button(submit and back). when i filled the page with Chrome Browser i got no problem.

but when i tried in chrome on my android phones i got some problem, here is the problem : first, i do select an option then when i want to fill the first textbox of the form the page has reload itself just like refreshing the page.

here is my code

```
<h1>Validate Confirm Payment</h1>   
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/payment/paidConfirm/<?php echo $order->id_order; ?>" name="form1" method="post">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>Transfer To</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="transfer_to" class="form-control" style="z-index:9999;">
                    <option value="0">--Select Name Bank--</option>
                    <option value="mandiri">Mandiri</option>
                    <option value="bca">BCA</option>
                    <option value="bri">BRI</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bank Account Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="bank_account_name" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bank Account Number</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bank_account_number" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Transfer Ammount</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="transfer_amount" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_order" value="<?php echo $order->id_order; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="status_confirm" value="1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/payment/index">Back</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

i dont really know what is wrong with my code or some methode that i dont know. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

As I can see, there is no problem in the HTML form code itself, but there should be some javascript listening to the on select change event.

If you can provide a link for the form you provided so that I can check the problem for you.

---

Try updating the chrome browser in your cell phone as lately the chrome browser had many bugs like that.

You can also check if there are some extensions or plugins installed in the android chrome browser itself [Ads plugins that makes an overlay divs]..

I had tested it on my cell phone and nothing goes wrong:

[screenshot from my android chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIsFk.png)

---

You can investigate if it is a javascript problem by adding onsubmit to the form:

```
<h1>Validate Confirm Payment</h1>   
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/payment/paidConfirm/<?php echo $order->id_order; ?>" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Really want to submit?');">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td>Transfer To</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="transfer_to" class="form-control" style="z-index:9999;">
                    <option value="0">--Select Name Bank--</option>
                    <option value="mandiri">Mandiri</option>
                    <option value="bca">BCA</option>
                    <option value="bri">BRI</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bank Account Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="bank_account_name" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bank Account Number</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bank_account_number" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Transfer Ammount</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="transfer_amount" style="z-index:9999;" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_order" value="<?php echo $order->id_order; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="status_confirm" value="1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/payment/index">Back</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: the chrome in my cell phones is up to date, but the page still do reload, i have tested in UC Browser theni dont know so well about javascript, can u added it one for me ?

Comment: Do you have a link so that I can investigate? I'll update the codes so that it help you check if it is really a JavaScript script listening to the form events.

Comment: i've the link but it is a company project, i cant let u investigate sir, the code that i gave is an active page.

Comment: I had updated the answer and added onsubmit to the form, so if the page is reloaded due to a submit, you will know. And you can cancel the submission by clicking on cancel. If no confirmation alert shows up, then it is not a javascript issue.. waiting to hear from you.